# Amazon API Gateway - Get next set of results from dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

everyone

I'm using Amazons API Gateway as a proxy for Dynamo DB. I've read through the documentation but I can't seem to find a lot of information about how to get the next set of items in a collection.

The documentation says that api gateway only returns 25 items at a time. I see under the api gateway documentation that it has a "next" call but I'm not sure how to use it.

For example, if i have an api such as **apiurl.com/videos/1** which references to the videos for a specified user ID how do i get the next set of videos in the collection.

This is my first time building an api or implementing a backend so it's a little confusing.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Could you please post some of the code you are using to give us a better basis?

Comment: Can you link to the API Gateway documentation you are referring to?

Comment: Sure, I've found this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/common/next/) but it doesn't tell me much

Comment: Yes this link is for API Management APIs, distinct from APIs you yourself run on API Gateway. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Please review this detailed blog post which answers your exact question:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/

Regarding the 25 item/request limit - this limit is imposed on items returned from API Gateway's management APIs. The limits imposed on APIs that you run on API Gateway itself (like your DynamoDB proxy API) have a separate set of limits. See [this document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html) for more details on both classes of limits. Additionally, DynamoDB itself will have [limits on its APIs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-api), such as 100 items per `BatchGetItem` and 1 MB per `Query` or `Scan`, that you will also have to take into consideration.

Comment: Thanks so much, I have figured I out a way to implement pagination using query string parameters. I will type it up so that hopefully it helps someone else. It was very frustrating trying to figure that out but the responses to my question helped.

Comment: @ZerryHogan Please share how you implemented pagination using query sting parameters